# Parsing string VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

please have at look on my issue.
I have following string `"F) GND G) FL240)"` in my Control.

I'm trying to parse the string between "F)" and "G)"  and also  between  "G)" and ")" with following code

```
If Left(s, 2) = "F)" Then
'Task - Filled ItemF  with value "GND"  or other values between  "F)" and "G)"  
        ItemF = Mid(s, InStr(s, "F)") + 3, Len(s) - InStr(s, "G)"))
```

'or

```
        'ItemF = Mid(s, InStr(s, "F)") + 3, Len(s) - Len(Right(s, InStr(s, "G)"))))
```

---

```
'Task - Filled ItemG  with value "FL240"  or other values between  "G)" and ")" 

 
            ItemG = Mid(s, InStr(s, "G)") + 3, Len(s) - InStr(s, "G)")) - how I can exclude last ")" 
        End If
```

Could you explain please, how to separate  and parse values between "F)" and "G)"  and also  between  "G)" and ")"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Split`:

```vb
FirstValue = Split(Split(s, "F) ")(1), " G)")(0)
SecondValue = Split(Split(s, "G) ")(1), ")")(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function -

```
Public Function fParseXML(sTag01 As String, sTag02 As String, sToParse As String) As String
 Dim pStart As Integer
 Dim pEnd As Integer
 Dim pLen As Integer
 If InStr(1, sToParse, sTag01) Then
  pStart = InStr(1, sToParse, sTag01) + Len(sTag01)
  pEnd = InStr(pStart, sToParse, sTag02)
  pLen = pEnd - pStart
  fParseXML = Mid(sToParse, pStart, pLen)
  Exit Function
 Else
  fParseXML = "Not found" & "**" & sTag01 & "**" & Mid(sToParse, 1, 100)
  Exit Function
 End If
```

use F) and G) and ) as the tags.

Comment: Thanks, it works,  but  when I try to change tag  to "G)" and ")" i get an error in fParseXML = Mid(sToParse, pStart, pLen)

Comment: @Vitaly Sorry I should have tested it first. Code changed and it works for me now.